# How can I restructure a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm relatively new to pandas and I am stuck on how to restructure a dataframe. Here is a very simplified example of what I want to do:

My current df is:

```
Name Company 20210102        
John X       Y
```

and I want to transform it to:

```
Date      Name Company Paycheck

20210102  John X       Y
```

I feel like I should be using pivot_table somehow but not sure how.. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Setting up the data will give you

```
data = { 'Name' : ['John'], 'Company' : ['X'], '20210102' : ['Y'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

and this data

```
   Name Company 20210102
0  John       X        Y
```

now using melt

```
print( pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name','Company'], var_name='20210102'))
```

will give you

```
   Name Company  20210102 value
0  John       X  20210102     Y
```

so finally

```
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name','Company'], var_name='20210102')
df2.columns = ['Name','Company','Date','Paycheck']
print(df2)
```

Yields

```
   Name Company      Date Paycheck
0  John       X  20210102        Y
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted...

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what `var_name` means. Passing `var_name='Date', value_name='Paycheck'` to `melt` saves you the rename `df.columns=...`

Comment: Thank you both Paul and Quang.. very helpful